# Why Eclipse not showing any warning or error for a basic maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

A simple code is written, I don't give ';' and '}' there must show a warning or error but it didn't show anything. When I try to import a user define class it does not show any user define class. I clean my project by clicking Project->Clean.. and I also check JRE and java compiler error/warning but everything looks fine. It is a maven project and normal projects are working fine. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your class into `src/main/java` instead of `src/main/resources`.

Comment: can you help with another problem? 
In maven when I am building a project with archetype-webapp then folder structure is different then where should I put my java code

Comment: Sorry, no questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

J symbol for class indicates that Java source files are not on the build path, Since Java file is treated as an ordinary resource.

Move your class to src/main/java.

[Eclipse JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-icons.htm)

Comment: I am new in this field. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. :)

Comment: @akashpal Welcome.

Comment: @akashpal would you mind accepting my answer if it resolves your issue?